# Making a PrimeNG progress bar update instantly

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a PrimeNG progress bar

```
<p-progressBar value="{{ percentage }}"></p-progressBar>
```

but when the percentage displayed is, say, 80%, the bar itself may indicate a percentage of, say, 50% as it continuously grows to catch up to 80%.

How do I get the progress bar's length to make a discrete jump to its correct value? My JavaScript, TypeScript and Angular knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, override the existing animation CSS:

```
.p-progressbar-determinate .p-progressbar-value-animate {
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Change it to

```
#myId .p-progressbar-value-animate {
    transition: none;
}
```

In the global style sheet of your application. You need to use an ID on the containing element and add that to your override CSS.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-progressbar-demo-2ypbrr?file=src/styles.css)

Comment: No change noticed

Comment: Please see edits and SB.